# Handle Mysql Error with same Error number

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I've a question.
I need to handle the Mysql error (like duplicate key, foreign constraints...) for example:

```
$id=$db->insert ('user', $data);
if(!$id){
    switch($db->getLastErrno()){
        throw new Exception(... );
    }
}
```

Here i use error number to select the right Exception.
But for the same error, what i've to do?
I think to use error string, for example:

```
if($db->getLastErrno()==1452 && strpos($db->getLastError(), "contraint name created on db")>-1){
    throw new Exception(... );
}
```

But i don't know why, i think it's a little bit trash. Does anyone have other solutions?

Comment: You're missing `case` in your `switch` statement

Answer (score 0):

Put the `if` statement inside the `case`. You don't need to repeat the error number test.

```
switch ($db->getLastErrno()) {
    case 1452:
        if (strpos($db->getLastError(), "constraint name created on db") !== false) {
            throw new Exception(...);
        }
        break;
    ...
}
```